# How to automate task in OllyDBG ? Using Ollyscript or any other tool

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I am debugging an app in OllyDBG. I want to create a script or automation. I set a breakpoint on a certain address and goto its stack arguments. There are four stack arguments.

I use the address of the 2nd argument and the size from the 4th argument and dump the HEX data in a log file. For example:

1. I set a breakpoint at `0x512A12`.
2. I see the following in stack:

   ```
   00192003   005DB123  RETURN to program.005DB123 from program.00512A12
   00192011   0018F058 - 1st argument
   00192028   03F48D78 - 2nd argument
   00192032   03F48D78 - 3rd argument
   00192036   00000500 - 4th argument
   ```
3. So, I dump the data from address starting at `0x00192028   03F48D78 - 2nd argument`. Which is `0x03F48D78`.
4. I use the size from the 4th argument - `00192036   00000500 - 4th argument`. Which is `500`.
5. Then, the data is saved in a log file. It is hex data from the dump section in Olly.

So, I want to loop this function and automate it.

How can this automation on Ollyscript or on something else created ?

Answer (score 1):

your thread is lacking more informations , like entrypoint and endpoint of your code , so my script isnt supposed to reach an end.

```
var v
var h
br:
cmp eip,00192003
jne label
mov v,[00192036]
mov h,[00192028]
dma h, v, "c:\dump.bin"
label:
sti
run
jmp br
```